# Having trouble scrolling down to element in Selenium, python

Tags: python, selenium, scroll

[image]I'm trying to get Selenium to scroll down on a page and then click on a button (the arrows on the bottom right under the "Add+") , but I keep getting a NoSuchElementException error. Here's what I've tried, but still nothing is working.

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

element = driver.find_element_by_xpath('/html/body/div[7]/div/div/main/section[6]/main/div/main/div[2]/section[1]/p/button')
element.click()
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is that element located in bottom of the page ? can you show us by screenshot where is it located in UI ?

Comment: Also did you try with `scrollIntoView`.

Comment: @pmadhu Yes, I've looked at many solutions on this board yet still nothing has worked. Maybe it's another issue?

Comment: @grxthy - Okay, share more details. Like URL. If its not possible to share the URL, update the question with HTML .

Comment: @cruisepandey Just added an image. The Xpath I want selenium to find is all the way at the bottom of that popup block.

Comment: Did you try this `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)`, you should  write this line before `element.click()` and see if that helps.

Comment: @cruisepandey this worked! If you don't mind, could you explain how this is different from scrollIntoView(0) or the method I first tried? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using

```
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

which is basically, to `scroll to the bottom of the page`.

Please use this :

```
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", element)
element.click()
```

this will basically scroll into the element view and element will be available in Selenium view port.